# How to increase image size dynamically in Swift, Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an application where an image is increasing in size and want to change the rate in which it does/be able to touch for a function. I'm new to Swift, thank you for anyone who helps. This is within "Game" applications of Xcode -- Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle-icon")
let num = 1
var grow = 0 
override func didMove(to view: SKView) (
    let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    bg.size = self.size
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2) bg.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(bg)


    image.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.2)
    image.zPosition = 1
    while grow < 10 {
        let growMore = grow
        image.setScale(CGFloat(growMore))
        grow += 0.1
          } 
    self.addChild(image)
   }
}
```

Comment: ive run into this as well, and unfortunately there doesnt seem to be a way to feed an SKAction anything other than a constant. you could try cancelling the in progress action and then adding a new SKAction with new parameters as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run an `SKAction` on the sprite you wish to scale. This example scales it to size 300x300 over a period of five seconds, but obviously you'd want to adjust that to your liking.

```
 let scale = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300), duration: 5.0)
 yourSprite.run(scale)
```

You can also scale by increments by using the separate scale method with different constructor `scale(by: )`